# SQL Profiler duration storing 0s

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I created a script to run a MDX statement multiple times, I'm trying to calculate average duration for it. I'm storing the results in a database table using SQL Profiler but in UI and database Duration sometimes shows 0s. Profiler created the table, Duration column is a bigint.
I found this on Microsoft documentation

> The server reports the duration of an event in microseconds (10^-6 seconds) and the amount of CPU time used by the event in milliseconds (10^-3 seconds). The SQL Server Profiler graphical user interface displays the Duration column in milliseconds by default, but when a trace is saved to either a file or a database table, the Duration column value is written in microseconds.

But even after activating the "Show values in Duration in microseconds" option, I still get some duration columns as 0.
I am using SQL Server 2017 and SQL Profiler 2017.

Comment: why not create a WHILE loop and run your code 1000 times?  Then simply divide the total time taken by 1000 for your average time.

Comment: @MJH I'll also take max and min time